# Scriptural Reference that say - "a Banyan tree represents Shiva"?

Tags: belief, symbolism, plants, banyan-tree

The Vaṭ, Bargad, or the [Indian Banyan tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_benghalensis) ( *Ficus benghalensis* ) is one of the most venerated trees within Hinduism.

Several times, it's told by people that the tree is a combined representation of the Trimūrtis. **Some people also say it's a direct manifestation of Lord Śhiva.**

[This](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/nagpur/Significance-of-the-Banyan/articleshow/8856719.cms) source says:

> In Hinduism, **the tree is called Kalpavriksha**, the tree that fulfills all wishes. **It symbolizes the Trimūrti** - Lord Brahmā is said to be its roots, Lord Viṣhṇu is said to be the bark, and Lord Śhiva is said to be the Branches of the Banyan tree.

Further,

> **The Banyan is associated with Yama the god of death** and the tree is also planted near the crematorium.

**Question:** Are the above-mentioned claims based on any canonical scriptures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Skandamahāpurāṇa 2.4.3.43 says "*a Banyan tree represents Shiva*".

> [Chapter 3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371644.html#note-t-139395), Kārttikamāsa-māhātmya, Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa
>
> अश्वत्थरूपी भगवा**न्वटरूपी सदाशिवः** ।
>  तस्मात्सर्वप्रयत्नेन
> कार्तिकेऽश्वत्थमर्चयेत् ॥ ४३ ॥
>
> > 43. Aśvattha is a form of the Lord (Viṣṇu) and **Vaṭa is a form of Sadāśiva.** Hence by all means one should worship Aśvattha in the month
> >     of Kārttika.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare

Answer (score 1):

In [Padma Purana;](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365267.html)

> The highest lord being Maheśvara, remains at Vaṭa.

As per [Shiva Purana,](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226060.html) Lord Shiva do penance at *Vata Vriksha*.

> 34. After going beyond Alakā, the capital of the king of Yakṣas and the Saugandhika park, **they saw the fig-tree of Śiva.** 35. The fig tree had steady shade all round. It had a number of suspended branches without hanging roots. Its height was a hundred Yojanas. It had no nests on it. It afforded protection from heat. 36. **It was the place where Śiva practised Yoga**. It was divine. It was resorted to by other Yogins. It was great and excellent. It could be seen only by the excessively meritorious persons. It was beautiful and sacred